# Is there a way to extract the value from AnyVal without knowing its exact type?

Tags: scala

The question is pretty much in the title.

As an example, consider the following code:

```
case class CustomerId(value: String) extends AnyVal

val someId: AnyVal = CustomerId("asdf-123")

def magicExtractor(anyAnyVal: AnyVal): String = ???

assert("asdf-123" == magicExtractor(someId))
```

Just stating the obvious, pattern matching over exhaustive list of all AnyVal subclasses is not an option.

Comment: Is the target always going to be a `case class`? Can "the value" be only a string? Is it always going to be the first item in the constructor and/or have the same name?

Comment: Further question: Scala 2 or Scala 3?

Comment: Are Shapeless/Mirrors/Macros and type class derivation allowed?

Comment: As mentioned, this requires reflection, but my gut tells me this is the wrong approach in the first place. Can you explain why this is wanted? Are you familiar with other tools or techniques that might help? (typeclasses, opaque types, etc. If this is Scala 3, I highly recommend opaque types with hierarchy)

Answer (score 1):

As AnyVal is the base class for all primitive types and user-defined value classes and JVM erases the type information the only way is to use reflection:

```
def magicExtractor(anyVal: AnyVal): String = {
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(anyVal.getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror = mirror.reflect(anyVal)
  val members = instanceMirror.symbol.typeSignature.members

  members.collectFirst {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isGetter => instanceMirror.reflectMethod(m).apply().toString
  }.getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to extract value"))
}
```

Would be nice if you share the way you have chosen at the end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).